# mount point changed

Tags: mount, automount, mountpoint

in my machine I have a partition that I mount after logging in.
Usually it is mounted in

```
/media/Data
```

Since yesterday (I don't know what I did)

it is mounted in

```
/media/Data_
```

and the mounting point `/media/Data` remains empty (with unknown size).

Does anyone have a clue about what happened?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For some reason the empty directory is not automatically deleted after the removal of the device

Therefore

- Remove the old mount point

  ```
  sudo rmdir /media/Data
  ```
- Remove the device and insert it again

Answer (score 2):

As there already is a folder named `/media/Data` the automounter creates another one named `/media/Data_` as mounting point to avoid using a folder that you may have created for something else.

If you remove the folder `/media/Data` the automounter will use `/media/Data` as mounting point the next time you mount your partition.

Maybe you didn't properly unmount the partition the last time so the mounting point didn't get removed.

Answer (score 1):

To avoid something like this in the future, I'd recommend, that you use the blkid of the device and create a new fstab entry.

E.g. (need to be root)

```
mars ~ # sudo blkid
/dev/sdb1: LABEL="backup" UUID="581df838-483f-432f-93ca-64945def428c" TYPE="xfs"
```

Entry in fstab

```
mars ~ # sudo nano /etc/fstab 
UUID="581df838-483f-432f-93ca-64945def428c" /backup xfs defaults 0 0
```

With this method, this exact device will always be mounted like you configured it in /etc/fstab, and your error/problem disappears.