# /media mount point name after power cut

Tags: mount, xubuntu, thunar

I had a power cut whilst an SSD was mounted. After restart, the mount point has been appended with '1' and the old mount dir is still there. I think it's a duplicate of [this problem](https://askubuntu.com/questions/601927/mount-point-changed) but would like to check as that question gets appended with an _

[http://i.imgur.com/svCjNup.png](https://i.imgur.com/svCjNup.png)

'Work' is the original, and 'Work1' the newly generated mount point

Sidenote: I mount this manually in Thunar. It's is an encrypted SSD and I hadn't figured out how to automount it in fstab (something like chaining into the user login)

Comment: Tried just deleting the old mountpoint?

Comment: Thank you, that worked. Is that a quirk that mine got appended with '1' rather than '_'?

Comment: I'd might as well make it an answer then, you can "officially" select it as correct (check-mark) in case anyone else browsing is curious

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the old mountpoint directory (`/media/oliver/Work`) was left behind from before the sudden shutdown & subsequent reboot, and then the system (or whatever program that automounts for you) didn't want to use it again (I'm not too sure why).

To fix it, just deleting the old mountpoint should work

```
sudo rm /media/oliver/Work
```

I'm not sure why it made a new folder named `Work1` instead of `Work_`, that's probably the default action for the automounting program. The other question may have been using a different desktop environment (it didn't specify) or the defaults have just changed since then.

---

If you've got Disks (`gnome-disk-utility`) installed, it's good at creating fstab entries, under a partition's "gear" icon (currently, until they change the UI again, it used to look very different) select "**Edit Mount Options**", then turning "Automatic Mount Options" Off.

Depending on how your drive's encrypted, you may need to look into using **`crypttab`**, and/or in Disks the "**Edit Encryption Options**".